# Javascript .css not working nor jquery .blue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, text-styling

I'm having all sorts of trouble styling simple html
in js and jQuery
It seems a jsfiddle is used here to illustrate.
I am new to it and don't see console output or the desired results
so I ask this question to learn more about how so can help;
I did search so for .css not working and variations

javascript

```
    .css() is jQuery.
    .style is js.
```

document.getElementsByTagName('pre').text.css("color: blue;");
jquery:
        const preSentences = $("pre").text().split(".")
        console.log({preSentences})

```
    //no err no workee in chrome
```

//        preSentences.forEach(function(str) { $(this).css("color: blue; border: 1px solid black")});
//        $.each(preSentences, function(str) { $(this).blue })
//        preSentences[1].style("color: blue; border: 1px solid black");

the fiddle is here I think - I tried the embed link and it doesn't show up:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lz8nh50o/

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName('pre').text.css("color: blue;")` not even close to valid use of native DOM methods. - Did you check the developer tools console for errors?

Answer (score 1):

getElementsByTagName will return an array of tags, and you have to loop through each one to set the style. Also, you are using .css() but that is a jQuery function. You have to use style.

Try this:

```
var preTags = document.getElementsByTagName('pre');
for(var i=0; i<preTags.length; i++){
  preTags[i].style.color='blue';
}
```

Comment: I see this works. A jquery equivalent would help me straighten out my understanding.

Comment: const jsts = document.getElementsByTagName('pre');

jsts.style.color='blue';

Comment: 'jsts' is an array of tags, you have to set the style individually to each tag. Try console.log(jsts) instead of console.log({jsts})

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate though the htmlCollention with ES6 for-of loop, it seems cleaner.

```
let list = document.getElementsByTagName('pre')

for (let currentElement of list){
    currentElement.style.color ='blue';
}
```

jQuery equivalent is

```
jQuery('pre').css('color','blue');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// JS
document.querySelectorAll('pre').forEach(str => {str.style.color='blue';})

//jQuery
jQuery('pre').css('color','blue');
```

Comment: document.querySelectorAll('pre').forEach(str => str.style.color='blue') . In this case you can even drop the curvy brackets and the semicolon.